# Is there a way to leave just one component and link's content on the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/navbar";
import Intro from "./components/intro/intro";
import Services from "./components/services/services";
import Experience from "./components/experience/experience";
import TrelloClone from "./pages/TrelloClone/TrelloClone";
import './App.css'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          {/* <Route path="/vanillajs" element={SpotifyClone} />
          <Route path="/djangoapi" element={InstagramClone} /> */}
          <Route path="/reactjs" element={<TrelloClone />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      <Intro />
      <Services />
      <Experience />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So basically I need to hide(or remove) `<Intro />`, `<Services />` and `<Experience />` by clicking the link that leads to '*/reactjs*' path but leave the `<Navbar />` on the page.

edit: grammar and clarifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install this `history` from [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history), when your package is installed successfully, create a file history.js and put the below code in this file.

```
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

import the history file in this file like `import history from './history'`, then you will get the history props and you can console the history props and check which props are coming and you will find `pathname` in the history props and make a condition and as you can see in the code below.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import history from './history'
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/navbar";
import Intro from "./components/intro/intro";
import Services from "./components/services/services";
import Experience from "./components/experience/experience";
import TrelloClone from "./pages/TrelloClone/TrelloClone";
import './App.css'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          {/* <Route path="/vanillajs" element={SpotifyClone} />
          <Route path="/djangoapi" element={InstagramClone} /> */}
          <Route path="/reactjs" element={<TrelloClone />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
      {history?.location?.pathname !== '/reactjs' && 
     <>
      <Intro />
      <Services />
      <Experience />
     </>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Hey, sorry to bother you but i don't really get how do i get the history props and what should i write instead of  the `pathname`. If i do `console.log(history.location.pathname)` there is just a `/` in the console.

Comment: Yes, if you console `console.log(history.location.pathname)`, they will show the path to the page `route`, for example, if you are on the homepage, they will show the pathname `/` and if you are on the`TrelloClone` page, they will show you the pathname `/reactjs` and you can hide the components based on the pathname.

Comment: or you can learn more about `history` from [this link](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/history)

Comment: i'm really sorry but if i do the `{history.location.pathname !== '/reactjs' && ... }` thing it gives me an error:
`Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /home/kay/Documents/Projects/portfolio-app/src/App.js: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>? (26:6)

  24 |       {history.location.pathname !== '/reactjs' &&
  25 |       <Intro />
> 26 |       <Services />
     |       ^
  27 |       <Experience />
  28 |       }
  29 |     </div>`

Comment: hi @kayoinc I have updated the code, can you please check and try again. thanks

Comment: Sorry to bother you I have again updated the code a little bit.

Comment: in fact, it works both with and without the question marks. Anyways, thank you very much!

Comment: No worries, I will be happy to help you again. :)